# Where does $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why does this sum diverge and does not converge towards 0?

$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n}$

I assume it's because there is no way to define how we count it I guess. However, is there a domain in mathematics where we would accept that this series is equal to zero, e.g.

$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(1-1)$

Comment: There are domains where we can assign a "sum-like" concrete value to this series. And among these domains, $\frac12$ is a much more popular choice than $0$.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation

Comment: @BrunoKrams that's totally what I was looking for!

Comment: _Wikipedia_ has several articles on this series. [This one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_of_Grandi%27s_series) may be the most relevant to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation